# Term vectors in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I'm trying to use the MoreLikeThis Solr's feature to find similar document based on some other document, but the I don't quite understand how some of this functionality works.

As it says [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/morelikethis.html), the MoreLikeThis component works best, when the `termVectors` are stored. And here comes my confusion.

Is it enough that I enable the flag `termVectors` on a field (let's say the field contains a movie review text) in Solr's schema.xml file? Will it make Solr calculate the termVectors for a given field after inserting it, store it and then use the calculcated termVectors in subsequent calls to the MoreLikeThis handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is NO, you need to re-index after such a schema change.
Having the term vector enabled, will speed up the process of finding the interesting terms from the original input document ( if this document is in the index).
Second phase timing (when More Like This query happens), will remain the same.
For more information about how the MLT works [1] .

In general, when applying such changes to the schema, you need to re-index your documents to make Solr builds the related data structures(the term vector is a mini index per document, and requires specific files to be stored on disk[2]
N.B. this will increase your disk utilisation)

[1] https://www.slideshare.net/AlessandroBenedetti/advanced-document-similarity-with-apache-lucene

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50TermVectorsFormat.html

Comment: I actually don't have a schema yet, nor do I have an indexed set of document. My Solr core is blank right now, I'm just starting. So, if I understood well - Solr will automatically build the term vectors for each document when indexing it, right?

Comment: Indeed, after you configure it in the schema, Solr will take care and build the data structures at indexing time.
The MLT will use the structures automatically ( internally the MLT code does a check on the index files, and in case it finds the term vector for the field it is evaluating, it will automatically use them)

Comment: Great, that's some good news. I'll actually have one more question, as I see that You have a very good understanding of the topic. 

When performing the MLT I want it to only consider a limited subset of the indexed document, for example: I have a index of 150 000 document,  the schema consists of id, title, content and publicationDate. 

Now, I want to perform a MLT query against an arbitrary input document, but I want the query to consider documents only with publicationDate between 02-01-2014 and 02-04-2014. 
Seems like the `mlt.qf` is the solution for it, am I right?

Comment: Here's a link do the documentation that I've found
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/morelikethis.html#MoreLikeThis-HowMoreLikeThisWorks

Comment: Ok, to do that I recommend to use the MLT query parser.
To do that you will require to follow this syntax :

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-MoreLikeThisQueryParser

Then you can add to your query parametric fq, such as the one you mentioned.
This basically will allow you to have control on the query built by the more like this, adding the part you like ( such as additional filters)

Comment: I see. So, I build the MLT query following the syntax from the documentation, put it to Solr's `q` parameter and then in the 'fq' parameter I  add my custom date filter, right?